# how to add the page border for first two pages in latex?

Tags: books, border

I'm beginner in latex. I'm trying crate a my internship report so i want to crate a page boarder for first two pages. i created the first page but at the second page is not getting boarders, it getting header and footers what i given. so please help me to put the boarder at second page also....

here what i have tried,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [line width=3pt]
       ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-2.0cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.8cm) $);
\draw [line width=1pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1.65cm,-2.15cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.65cm,1.95cm) $); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{\large{DECLARATION}}

%-----some paragraph-------

\newpage

\begin{center}
\section*{\large{ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}}
\end{center}

%-----some paragraph-------
\end{titlepage}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage 

\pagenumbering{arabic}

%-----Start chapters-------
\end{document}
```

**(in code I'm not mention the header and footers)**

I searched lots but i got only how to add one page boarders so help me to put border for two pages also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Here is one possible way using `eso-pic`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\ifnum\value{page}<3% <- change this if you want more
% or less pages to have a frame
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [line width=3pt]
       ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-2.0cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.8cm) $);
\draw [line width=1pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1.65cm,-2.15cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.65cm,1.95cm) $); 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}


\section*{DECLARATION}

%-----some paragraph-------

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\large\bfseries ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
\end{center}

%-----some paragraph-------
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\chapter{Some chapter}
%-----Start chapters-------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank u so much for your answer.I have small problem i tried your code, it works for me but the board is applying 1St chapter also and the second page acknowledgement's page board is coming along with header and footers .what changes i have to make?

Comment: @sathyamurthy Better now?

Comment: Actually better but i don't want borders in chapters can u change that ? it is possible?

Comment: @sathyamurthy I am sorry, I cannot understand what you are saying. What does " i don't want borders in chapters" mean?

Comment: Actually in the book template chapters (only chapter page)did not have headers and footers  in the next page (same chapter only) header and footers will come.but it is overlapping the header and footers with the boarders in the next page (chapter's second page)

Comment: thank U its working thank u so much

Comment: I'm Using Page number as roman(i,ii,iii,iv...) and Arabic(1,2,3) this the reason the chapter having the borders .AddToShipoutPictureBG{\ifnum\value{page}<2 this command will help to add the boarder to 1,2(roman,Arabic both) pages .plz help me to apply boarder to only roman page numbered pages only

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me - it maybe useful for others. In a `book` type of document - I wanted first page to have border. Note the use of `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` instead of `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{}`.

```
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
    \makeatletter
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \draw [line width=3pt]
            ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-2.0cm) $)
            rectangle
            ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.8cm) $);
            \draw [line width=1pt]
            ($ (current page.north west) + (1.65cm,-2.15cm) $)
            rectangle
            ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.65cm,1.95cm) $); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \input{./coverpage/coverpage-thesis}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: This is covered in large part by the current (accepted) answer. I'd suggest turning your reference to `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` rather than `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` into a comment.